# Java's TreeSet implementation of contains (Sourcecode) missing

Tags: java, treeset, language-implementation

When I open the sourcecode of the TreeSet Class there is the following code:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return m.containsKey(o);
}
```

m is a NavigableMap which is an interface. So where is the implementation? It is definitely not in TreeSet itself.

Comment: Did you find out what `m` is, and look for the source code of `m`'s class's `containsKey` method?

Comment: Ok sry, I feel dumb now. m is a NavigableMap but it is instantiated as TreeMap and there I did find the implementation. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source for `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet(NavigableMap<E,Object> m) {
    this.m = m;
}

public TreeSet() {
    this(new TreeMap<E,Object>());
}
```

So `m` should be a `TreeMap` (or possibly another implementation of `NavigableMap` if another class in the same package calls that constructor).

Comment: The `TreeSet(NavigableMap<E,Object> m)` constructor is package-only scoped, so it can't just be any `NavigableMap` - it's only possible to construct a `TreeSet` with a `TreeMap`, or ones constructed by `TreeSet` from submaps of `TreeMap`

Comment: Yeah you are right. I missed that NavigableMap m could actually be the superinterface of a class implementing it...
In eclipse I clicked on m and then "Open Declaration" but then the Interface of NavigableMap opened ... I don't know why I didn't think of it myself.. I should go to bed

Comment: Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes on things. Happens to everybody.